# JavaScript matrix bounds are incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I need to write a function that returns a function that generates a 2D array. The function mult(x,y) should return a function to generate a multiplication table, and calling generate_matrix() should return the matrix.

```
    function mult(x,y){
            function generate_matrix(){
                var matrix = new Array(x);
                for(var k = 0; k < x+1; k++){
                    matrix[k] = new Array(y);
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < x+1; i++){
                    for(var j = 0; j < y+1; j++){
                        matrix[i][j] = i*j;
                    }
                }
                return matrix;
            }
            return generate_matrix;
        }
```

For some reason, the matrix is 100 times larger than it should be. For example, if I set var matrix = mult(5,5), then call matrix(), I am given an array of size 50x50 instead of an array of size 5x5.

I set `var m = mult(2,2)`, then call `m()`, I should get the following 2D array:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[0,2,4]]
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you say it does.

Comment: Can you post an example of valid output given some input?

Comment: @elclanrs If I set var m = mult(2,2), then call m(), I should get the following 2D array:
[[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[0,2,4]]

Comment: @Pointy could you be more specific? My explanation may not have been clear enough. My function works as it is supposed to (generates a multiplication table), but the table itself is too large (too many entries).

Comment: Worked fine when I ran it...

Comment: Why are you passing `x` for the length in the Array constructors but iterating until `x+1`?

Comment: The given code looks correct. Perhaps there is something in the context of use that is causing the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Bergi Good observation, `new Array(x+1)` is preferred here; but `new Array(x)` won't cause any observable problem since (unless I am mistaken) an assignment like `array[array.length] = value;` is legal in javascript.

Comment: @nh0815 the code works, and does not generate a matrix 100 times bigger than requested.

Comment: @Pointy the code works when run in the console, but wouldn't work when called from HTML (not really sure why that is). I figured out that the problem was that the 1 being added was interpreted as a string, not an int. This meant the bounds had an extra place value, which would explain the 100 times larger problem.

Comment: @nh0815 if it was being interpreted as a string, it's because it **was** a string. If you're taking values from the DOM (like input field values), they're *always* strings, and you have to explicitly coerce them to integers. The JavaScript `+` operator is biased in favor of string concatenation (!).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I think this is what you want.

You can test this on following link : http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/Wt5gQ/33/

```
function mult(x, y) {
            var matrix = new Array(x);
            for (var k = 0; k < x + 1; k++) {
                matrix[k] = new Array(y);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < x + 1; i++) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML + "[";
                for (var j = 0; j < y + 1; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = i * j;
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML + matrix[i][j] + ",";
                }
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML + "]" + "<br/>"
            }
            alert(matrix);
            return matrix;
        }
```